# Can towering be used as a lone adjective?

Tags: word-usage

I think you can write sentences like "He was towering above me."

But can you write: "He was towering and good-looking."?

Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "He was towering above me."

In that case it is being used as a verb.

> "He was towering and good-looking."

When using it like this, if you want an official stance on the legality, it's listed in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary as acting as an adjective [only before a noun](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/towering]).

To play it safe and sound like legal English, you could say **"He was a towering and good-looking man."**  Even though it's not *immediately* before the noun, it modifies the noun "man".

If you're taking liberties with language--writing a song lyric or something--you could probably get away with it as written.  Though it'd probably come off like a foreign electro-synth band.  :-)

```
he was to-wer-ing ...
and good look-ing...
```